# Multiple Hostapd running in same wired LAN

Tags: ieee802.1x

I am using wpa_supplicant, hostapd and freeradius. I am using wired LAN.

Is it possible to connect wpa_supplicant to multiple hostapd in wired LAN environment?

If wpa_supplicant can connect multiple hostapd then how does it make a difference between different hostapds.

As I have seen in wpa_supplicant configuration file there is a network block. *How do I configure this network block so that it can connect multiple hostapd.*

Answer (score 0):

For wired LANs, the 802.1X Authenticator usually built into the 802.1X-capable switch, and the switch ensures that 802.1X frames are not forwarded beyond the built-in Authenticator.

If you've created a LAN where 802.1X frames can reach multiple Authenticators, you have not created a proper 802.1X-compliant LAN.

Comment: Hi thnx for your answer. I don't have a 802.1X-capable switch. I am using 3 linux pc, two of them running hostapd and one pc running wpa_supplicant. 3 machines are connected to same Lan segment. My question is if this set up is valid or not? or is it like only one hostapd can run with the wpa_supplicant in a Lan segment.

Comment: @debjyoti No, your setup is not valid. 802.1X on a wired LAN is useless if your switch is not blocking non-802.1X traffic to/from your client until after 802.1X authentication completes. It's also invalid if more than one Authenticator is reachable from your Supplicant.

Comment: Hi Spiff, Earlier u have mentioned about 802.1X-compliant LAN. can you tell me how can i set up  802.1X-compliant LAN?? I have 3 linux pc two of them running hostapd and one pc running wpa_supplicant. I dont have any switch. please suggest me some solution. Thanks in advance